# Rollup is not generating my "types" declarations folders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rollup, rollupjs

I don't know why but my rollup config does not generate anymore my types folders when bundeling my application (it used to some months ago), here are my config files :

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "rollup": "rollup -c"
  },
  "main": "lib/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "lib/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "rollup": "^2.77.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-ignore": "^1.0.10",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

**rollup.config.js :**

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({
        browser: true
      }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      json(),
      postcss(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "lib/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "lib/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', /\.css$/]
  },
];
```

**tsconfig.json :**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@root/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react", 
    "module": "ESNext",  
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
  }
}
```

I have this error now (due the inexistance of lib/esm/types/index.d.ts) :
[image]

And the content of the folders (missing types folder) :

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out why it wasn't working anymore?